Limit header forward to internal request
I have Spring Gateway 2023.0.3 project which I want to configure to limit only internally to forward headers from network requests. Example request:
API client -> Spring gateway -> Spring Authorization server

After that Spring gateway gets Bearer token and makes requests to microservices.
I managed to make it work by adding:
@Component
@Order(2)
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<CustomAuthorizationFilter.Config> {

    public CustomAuthorizationFilter() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            final StringBuilder jwtToken = new StringBuilder();
            exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().forEach((headerName, headerValues) -> {
                for (String value : headerValues) {
                    if (value.contains("Bearer")) {
                        System.out.println("Header with Bearer token found: " + headerName + " = " + value);
                        jwtToken.append(value);
                    }
                }
            });

            exchange.getRequest().mutate()
                        .header("Authorization", jwtToken.toString())
                        .build();

            return chain.filter(exchange);
        };
    }

    public static class Config {
    }

}

.....
  routes:
    - id: auth
      uri: lb://internal
      predicates:
        - Path=/platform/**
      filters:
        - name: CircuitBreaker
        - name: CustomAuthorizationFilter
          args:
            name: auth
        - RemoveResponseHeader=Cookie

Into very old version of Spring gateway it's working fine. But now request is not forwarded properly. I need to add and allow CustomAuthorizationFilter. It's a security issue because external API clients should not be allowed to pass requests with Bearer token. Do you know any possible solution?

Could you please add java import for your annoation?

You are saying that CustomAuthorizationFilter that you added in properties is not working in newer version spring gateway?

Can you elaborate the question as it is not very clear to me?

I'm saying that the forward of the internal Authorization header is working after I add a custom CustomAuthorizationFilter

@PeterPenzov Oh! Gotcha!

@PeterPenzov Do you mind providing a mininum code example to reproduce? Asking so that I can test.

Yes, I will write you later today on your email and send you example code.

@AnishB. if you need to ask for code via email, then please at least flag the question as off-topic. Or, if the OP supplies code privately, please edit the question so other readers can see it. Private comms here defeats the purpose of helping in public, which is that questions contain enough information for people to be able to help.

@halfer Ok. I agree with you. Let me see what can I do to edit it.

Thank you @AnishB. I look forward to seeing that change shortly.

You can try adding a logic to allow only internal requests (those coming from trusted sources, such as the Gateway itself) to forward the Bearer token header.
@Component
@Order(2)
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<CustomAuthorizationFilter.Config> {

    public CustomAuthorizationFilter() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            // Check if request is internal
            String clientIp = exchange.getRequest().getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress();
            if (isInternalRequest(clientIp)) {
                final StringBuilder jwtToken = new StringBuilder();
                exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().forEach((headerName, headerValues) -> {
                    for (String value : headerValues) {
                        if (value.contains("Bearer")) {
                            System.out.println("Header with Bearer token found: " + headerName + " = " + value);
                            jwtToken.append(value);
                        }
                    }
                });

                exchange.getRequest().mutate()
                            .header("Authorization", jwtToken.toString())
                            .build();
            }
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        };
    }

    // Check if the request is from a trusted internal IP
    private boolean isInternalRequest(String clientIp) {
        // Add your logic here to verify only internal IP ranges or trusted proxies
        return clientIp.startsWith("192.168.xxx") || clientIp.startsWith("10.xxx");
    }

    public static class Config {
    }
}

And, ensure that only requests from the gateway or internal services can pass the Authorization header. For this, you can add a RemoveRequestHeader filter to strip the Authorization header from any incoming requests from external clients before it reaches the CustomAuthorizationFilter.
routes:
  - id: auth
    uri: lb://internal
    predicates:
      - Path=/platform/**
    filters:
      - RemoveRequestHeader=Authorization # Remove Authorization header from external requests
      - CustomAuthorizationFilter # Add the token for internal use after validation
      - name: CircuitBreaker
      - RemoveResponseHeader=Cookie

With this setup, external clients' Authorization headers will be removed before forwarding, and the custom filter will re-add the Bearer token only if the request is from a trusted internal source.

Thanks for the proposal but I have this microservice running on Kubernetes and on different env. It will be hard to hardcode this or define it into property file every time. Is there any other possible solution?

If you cannot do it inside the code then you can create environment-wise files for all your configs and get it deployed on server anywhere and read the properties dynamically.
In any way, there will be some hardcoded values which you need to configure if you want to achieve some certain level of security.

Can you write me for example your e-mail so that I can show you the custom code that I added? I would like to show you the complete picture.

@PeterPenzov: it is not forbidden to ask for private communication addresses here, but it is not ideal. The point of Stack Overflow is do all help in public, so that other people can be helped. If you obtain help in private then it hides that help from other people.
